# Output only a part of a view-html file in laravel

Tags: php

inside the folder scourcode/scr is a view-html file.

I want to display only a part of the html-code if the user has a specific permission

`<div>Block1</div><div>Block2</div>`

Is it possible and if it's how, to do a kind of that

```
`<?php if($user->permission=='admin'){ ?> 
<div>Block1</div> 
<?php }else{ ?> 
<div>Block1</div><div>Block2</div> 
<?php } ?>`
```

How can I do that.

Enter php code in this file, failed. The code will not parsed and will display as it is.

Comment: `if($this = 1)` ? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & WP: Render Certain Markup Based on True False Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913946/php-wp-render-certain-markup-based-on-true-false-condition)

Comment: ($this == 1) for example, i've update the text

Comment: I hope this code isn't in a class.

Comment: no in a sourecode/src/ view .html file

Comment: @StefB `PHP` code not working on `.html` file

Comment: so you want to say that is impossible to do?

Comment: i've update the code to specificate my question

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
<?php 
    if($this==1){ ?> // write `==` instead of `=`
        <div>Block1</div> 
    <?php }else{ ?> 
        <div>Block1</div>
        <div>Block2</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

in Laravel View

```
@if($this==1)
    <div>Block1</div> 
@else
    <div>Block1</div>
    <div>Block2</div> 
@endif
```

Comment: @ is in lavarel the same as "<?php" and "?>" and every row wich php code has to begin with a @?

Comment: yes view file is also `view.blade.php` `.php` extension @StefB

Comment: `<div>Block1</div> @if($this != 1) <div>Block2</div>@endif` ?

Comment: ya its working when your code in `.php` file not `.html` file

Comment: it wont work - i've update the code to specificate my question

Comment: what you should exactly share your whole page code. and what was the your page extension?